# Ignoring routes i set in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

If I write the following in Laravel:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    echo "here"; exit();
});
```

and navigate to public/ it's fine!

---

If I write the following:

```
Route::get('/a', function()
{
    echo "a here"; exit();
});
```

And then navigate to public/a

It throws `"Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException"`

This was working a few days ago so it may be something to do with xampp? But i'm pretty sure mod_rewrite is on?

The `htaccess` file is untouched

Comment: I think it is mod rewrite, just tested index.php/a and that worked.. so :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `public` directory should be your webroot. Apache does some strange things with .htaccess and the file that Laravel provides, assumes that it is present in the webroot and not a second level directory.

Try configuring xampp so that the vhost has `/yourxampppath/laravel/public` as the webroot.

Below is an example of the standard vhost that I use. I don't actually use xampp, I have my own development server, but the principal remains the same.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hostname.ollieread.com
    ServerAlias hostname.ollieread.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hostname.ollieread.com
    ErrorLog logs/hostname.ollieread.com-error_log
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of a vhost.. It belongs in the httpd-vhosts file in etc right?

Comment: There you go. Obviously with this though, you'd want ServerName and ServerAlias to be something `mylaravel.localhost`, then you just need to edit your hosts file (`C://Windows/drivers/etc/hosts` iirc), so that `mylaravel.localhost` binds to the IP `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. crazy how it worked before. meh, what ya gnna do!